# About the definition of a class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Moschovakis:

> A unary definite condition $P$ is coextensive with a set $A$ if the objects which satisfy it are precisely the members of $A$, in symbols $$P=_e A\iff \forall x(P(x)\leftrightarrow x\in A)$$

$\dots$

> By definition, a class is either a set or a unary definite condition which is not coextensive with a set.

On an intuitive level I've always thoght that classes are "big sets" (which cannot be sets because of their sizes), but according to this definition, it turns out that a class that is not a set is a "condition". So if a class is not a set, it cannot contain elements. In particular, $\{x:x\not\in x\}$ is not a class. Is my understanding correct?

Next, I'm also confused by

> For every set $A$, $\{x:x\in A\}=A$ and, **in particular, every set is a class.**

Isn't the part in bold true by the definition of a class above?

---

Addition: in other sources, a class is defined as an object of the form $\{x: x\text{ is a set with property } P\}$. How is it consistent with the above definition?

---

I think Moschovakis is being a little floppy in treating classes. He says

> We will now profess that *for every unary, definite condition $P$ there exists a* **class** $$A=\{x:P(x)\},$$ such that for every object $x$, $$x\in A\iff P(x).$$

but then defines a class as being either a set (which is fine) or a certain condition (which is not fine because a condition is not of the form he claimed above).

Here is a "solution" proposed by Arturo Magidin (I hope I understood that correctly).

**Definition.**

(1) A **class** $C$ is the collection of all sets and atoms satisfying some definite unary condition $P$. In symbols, $C=\{x:P(x)\}$.

(2) A class $C$ is **coextensive with a set** $A$ if $$\forall x (P(x)\leftrightarrow x\in A)$$ or equivalently $C=A$.

EDIT: Probably I shouldn't say $C=A$ because the notion of equality of classes wasn't defined. On the other hand, I think one can define it by $C=A$ if $\forall x (P(x)\leftrightarrow x\in A)$.

(3) A class $C$ is **proper** if $C$ is not coextensive with any set. Equivalently, $C$ is not equal to a set.

In particular, any set is a class. Indeed, let $A$ be a set. Consider the class $\{x:x\in A\}$. This class is coextensive with the set $A$, i.e., $A=\{x:x\in A\}$. Since the RHS is a class, so is the LHS. This shows that any set is a class. In fact, this even shows that any set is a non-proper class.

Comment: You *can* think of classes as “things that are too big to be sets”. Every set is defined by a condition, but not every condition defines a set. In BGN, for example, a set is **defined** to be a class $A$ with the property that there is a class $X$ such that $A\in X$; that is, sets are those classes that are *elements* of other classes. And a proper class is a class that is not a set.  As to your final question, remember that those “other sources” probably don’t allow ur-elements, so the definition would be identical to the one you give: coextensive with $P$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If I accept the first approach (from Moschovakis' book) and if I don't mix different axiomatic systems, then I don't see any justification of why I can think of classes (which are *conditions*) as "things that are too big to be sets": the latter things (in my understanding) can contain elements, whereas conditions cannot contain elements.

Comment: each condition determines a collection (the collection of all sets and ur-elements that satisfy the condition); each collection determines a condition (the condition of being an element of the collection). Thus, collections are in bijective correspondence with conditions, and you can think of them inter-changeably.

Comment: So then I can define a class as "either a set or the collection of all sets and ur-elements that satisfy a unary definite condition which is not coextensive with a set"? And what about the inference "in particular, every set is a class" - how does it follow from $\{x: x\in A\}=A$, and why is that remark given if every set is a class by definition?

Comment: If you define a class as “either a set or `blah`“, then trivially every set is a class. But that is not the point. A class is just “the collection of all sets and ur-elements that satisfy a unary definite condition.” You don’t separate away those that are not sets. You then define  a **proper** class as a class that is not coextensive with a set. You then prove that a set $A$ is a class via the unary definite condition “$x\in A$”. It then follows that there are exactly two types of classes: sets, and proper classes.

Comment: P.S. I am not familiar with Mochovakis; and certainly, you have not provided all context (nor should you be expected to). So it is certainly possible some of the things I am saying are not *quite* right given his definitions. These are just the standard ways to reconcile these notions in most theories, modulo the precise definitions that may be involved in those theories. The theories I am more familiar with are ZFC and GBN.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What do you mean by "prove that a set $A$ is a class *via the unary definite condition* $x\in A$"? And how does it follow that there are exactly two types of classes? EDIT: For the first question, I just realized that you mean "prove that a set $A$ is the collection of all sets and ur-elements satisfying the unary definite condition $x\in A$"

Comment: You are reading into that statement more than what that statement says. That statement just shows that every set is a class, nothing more. **Then**, **separately**, you define a proper class as a class that is not co-extensive with a set. **Then** this definition shows that there are exactly two types of classes: sets, and proper classes.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, I hope I now understood the point. I've edited the question to include the "solution" you proposed.

Comment: Consider a proper class as just an abbreviation, not an actual object of the formal language. For example,  for the class $On$ of ordinals, writing $x\in On$ is an abbreviation for  "($x$ is well-ordered by $\in$ and  $\forall y\in x\,(y\subset x)\;).$"